# Creating Windows Store App Pages Without XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am writing a C#/XAML Windows Store app and would like to create and navigate to and display a Page entirely from C#. Is this possible? Obviously I can inherit from Page, but, when attempting to Navigate to a derived Page that has no XAML, I get a System.TypeLoadException... "Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation'".

My thought was this should be possible since XAML translates into a CLR partial class definition, so there's no reason one couldn't do everything in C#. But obviously I missing some sort of framework requirement.

Suggestions?

Right now all I have for the derived Page is

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1 {
    public class Page2 : Page {
        public Page2 () { }
    }
}
```

And here is the full exception:

```
Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation'.
at System.StubHelpers.WinRTTypeNameConverter.GetTypeFromWinRTTypeName(String typeName, Boolean& isPrimitive)
at System.StubHelpers.SystemTypeMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(TypeNameNative* pNativeType, Type& managedType)
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType)
at App1.MainPage.<P2>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Why would you want to mix your logic and presentation to spit on mvvm?

Comment: Does it matter? I am asking how to do it and if it's possible, not if it's a good idea.

Comment: Bump. Looking for the same thing. Anyone?

Comment: pec1985, I haven't been able to find anything other than that it looks pretty clear that XAML is required. Specifically, you need at least one root control in the XAML file. This could be a custom control that does little more provide a reference to the partial class defined in the code.

Comment: @cacti, me again. It's been a while, any news? Have you been able to this? Cheers.

Comment: @cacti Having the exact same problem, any updates so far?

Comment: Hi @cacti, have you been successful in the mean time? I am encoutering a similar issue at the moment ans have not gotten any usable answers so far... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986073/error-vb-runtime-is-not-loaded

Answer (score 0):

I can give an example for a simple page

```
using System;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Start((p) => new MyApp());
        }
    }
    class MyApp : Windows.UI.Xaml.Application
    {
        public MyApp(){}
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            var layoutRoot = new Grid() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) };
            layoutRoot.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "Hello!" });
            Window.Current.Content = layoutRoot;
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
}
```

Replace these paths with the correct items when compiling:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /target:appcontainerexe /r:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" /r:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.dll" /r:"C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata\windows.applicationmodel.winmd" /r:"C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata\windows.ui.winmd" /r:"C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata\windows.ui.xaml.winmd" /r:"C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata\windows.media.winmd" MyApp.cs
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create dynamic XAML using LINQ and XML.

Here's an example on how to create a dynamic *TextBlock*; you can use the concept to apply it to a *Page* element:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189044(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thank you, that is interesting. Unfortunately it still requires an XAML file to set up the root object (which is then populated dynamically). I am looking to avoid any XAML declarations at all.

Comment: The issue here is not how to do things in XAML, but how to navigate in code behind.