# System.TypeLoadException Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation' exception

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 app I'm creating a CustomPage and then navigating to it, all in code behind. My CustomPage class is:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace TestApp {
    public class CustomPage : Page {
        public CustomPage() {
            this.BuildPage();
        }

        private void BuildPage() {
            var panel = new StackPanel();
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Hello World" });
            this.Content = panel;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my `MainPage.xaml.cs` I'm doing this:

```
CustomPage myNewPage = new CustomPage();
Frame.Navigate(myNewPage.GetType());
```

However this throws a System.TypeLoadException exception - `Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation'`
If I don't do a CustomPage class just a Page class, it works fine, but I need to create a CustomPage class, how could I solve this?

**UPDATE**
This is the Stack Trace

```
MyCustomClass.DLL!HelpingTool.NavigateToNewPage() Line 50   C#
MyCustomClass.DLL!HelpingTool.InitializeToolset() Line 23   C#
MyCustomClass.DLL!HelpingTool.HelpingTool(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page mainPage = {TestApp.MainPage}) Line 18  C#
TestApp.exe!TestApp.MainPage.Button_Click(object sender = {Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button}, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e = {Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs}) Line 88 C#
```

And the content of my MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Loaded="Page_Loaded"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="OutputText">
                    Output will appear here <LineBreak />
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button Content="Do something" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Please show us your XAML.

Comment: There is no XAML, I'm creating the page entirely in code.

Comment: The fact that you've got `MainPage.xaml.cs` certainly makes it *sound* like there's some XAML. Have you really not got a XAML file *at all* for this? Please could you include the stack trace so we can see where it's failing?

Comment: The MainPage.xaml is indeed a XAML page, however it's content is irrelevant for this case, since I have nothing else than what is set by default. I'll add the Stack to the post in a second.

Comment: I would include the XAML anyway - until you know what's wrong, it's hard to know what's irrelevant...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662723/creating-windows-store-app-pages-without-xaml

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the Stack Trace and XAML, do you have any idea where the problem might be?

Comment: I notice that you have a Click event declared, but no backing event handler.

Comment: There is an event handler for that click, that is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi @ricochete, have you been successful in the mean time? I am encountering a similar problem at the moment, but cannot find anything useful. This is my question / situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986073/error-vb-runtime-is-not-loaded

Comment: Hi @PeterKlein, unfortunately, I didn't found a way for this to work. If I remember correctly I ended up creating a normal page, because you can do that even in a `PCL`, which was my case.

Comment: @ricochete, thanks for you reaction. I am still busy trying to overcome the issue. We have invested too much to abandon the road now.