# Error: VB runtime is not loaded

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

**Edited version, after suggestion from community:**

In a `Windows 8.1` Phone project (Part of a `VB.Net` Solution with also a Store app and a Portable Class Library) I get this error message:

> Call not possible because VB Runtime is not loaded.

but as far as I can trace the code keeps running in spite of this. Until... eventually an error pops up, telling me that

> Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.foundation'

What I have found so far on this subject seems to have a relation with Silverlight and very old versions of VB Runtime. Nothing recent.

Further on during execution in the error trap the following explanation is given:

> at System.StubHelpers.WinRTTypeNameConverter.GetTypeFromWinRTTypeName(String typeName, Boolean& isPrimitive)
>      at System.StubHelpers.SystemTypeMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(TypeNameNative* pNativeType, Type& managedType)
>      at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType)
>      at Dossier365.Mobile.Behaviors.MenuTegelClickAction.ReageerOpMenuKeuze(Object sender, Object parameter).

I have attached a screenshot with the different messages. The Store App runs fine, based on the same PCL.

**EDIT: after suggestions below: added DirectCast:**

[image]

Now a new error message appears: I have no clue what goes on here or moreover: how to overcome this situation. My attempts so far have not lead to a workable solution.

Anyone with a good suggestion or solution?

Comment: It is an environmental error, the code is not running in full trust.  There are no breadcrumbs in the question to guess why this happened.  Common reasons are running code from a wonky file share instead of the C: drive or using a .NET assembly that you obtained from a download through the Internet or attached to an email message.

Comment: @HansPassant, this helps only partly, unfortunately. The code is definitely running from a local C: drive. All references that are in use in de solution are from "solid" NuGet installations.

Comment: @HansPassant, if you could give me some sugestions how to provide breadcrumbs, I would be more than prepared to do so! Or please elaborate on what you mean by "environmental error". Did I cause that? and why is the rest of the code running allright?

Comment: What is the type you try to set in the `PaginaType` variable? Is that a class you implemented yourself, or an external library?

Comment: Hi @KooKiz, Thanks for your reaction. The PaginaType is a standard System.Object.Type. But plz realize that the error has to do with the line above the message, namely the String.Format statement. That is what makes it so weird...!

Comment: Indeed, the exception is thrown by the getter of the ItemClickEventArgs.ClickedItem property. As to understand why... You're doing some late-binding, could you try casting the object before accessing the property? `Dim item as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemClickEventArgs = parameter` then use `item.ClickedItem.UniqueId` in the string.Format

Comment: @KooKiz, I'm busy trying that, but the project looks like it's falling apart at the moment. Instead of the normal startscreen, the screen goes black now... I guess there's some extra work needed in other places as well. I will keep you posted on this subject when I get any results! Thanks

Comment: I have posted a new edited version of the Original question after the suggestion by @KooKiz. BTW Thanks for that, it seems one step further...

Comment: ... wow. What's the line throwing the error this time, the DirectCast or the string.Format?

Comment: In fact it's the frame.navigate statement. The code runs all the way up to there, and then jumps to the error. What is in between is all standard Prism code. You can tell based on the small red lines below the code that the page that should be navigated to could be resolved("Dossier365.Mobile.Views.ZorgRapportage"), thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: There are similar questions to this one by ricochete and by cacti. I will provide links to these - also unsolved - questions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662723/creating-windows-store-app-pages-without-xaml     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213950/system-typeloadexception-could-not-find-windows-runtime-type-windows-foundation